# @react-native-community/netinfo: NativeModule.RNCNetInfo is null after install latest version

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install, react-native-community-netinfo

I have updated react native version from **0.57 to 0.59.1**. After successful updated it throws error in react native info, so i installed @react-native-community/netinfo and removed Netinfo from react-native.

**I have run below commands to install latest version of netinfo:**

npm install --save @react-native-community/netinfo

react-native link @react-native-community/netinfo

cd ios && pod install

After successful linking when run my project i got error @react-native-community/netinfo: NativeModule.RNCNetInfo is null...

I also tried with version 3 of netinfo but same error occurred.

**Version:**

@react-native-community/netinfo: ^5.3.2

react: ^16.8.3

react-native": ^0.59.1

Please help me if anyone have solution for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Getting this in RN0.62.2.
Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting this error while running jest test. Add following file to be used as a mock
[source](https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo/issues/75#issuecomment-488277512)

add a mock for the NetInfo bridge module and you need not update the Jest config...

file location ==>
__mocks__/@react-native-community/netinfo.js

```
export default {
  getCurrentConnectivity: jest.fn(),
  isConnectionMetered: jest.fn(),
  addListener: jest.fn(),
  removeListeners: jest.fn(),
  isConnected: {
    fetch: () => {
      return Promise.resolve(true);
    },
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
    removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
  },
};
```

Comment: Any idea to mock it for Mocha/Chai setup?

Comment: i feel mock object would remain same, you can look about details of chai setup

Comment: I'm a newbie on RN, any reference you're aware of?

Answer (score 0):

```
npx react-native-clean-project
```

It will remove all unnecessary files which are not required by the project but are attached with your project during `npm install`. These type of errors are mostly treated by cleaning of your project by using: `npx react-native-clean-project` in React Native.

For doing same thing in android studio, we use :

**Build** > **Clean Project**

*Hope it helps and solve your issue. Happy to help :)*

Comment: what does this do? Please put more info

Comment: it cleans your project and deletes all unnecessary files which are responsible for such type of errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mac to emule your device.

try:

macOS Platform:

Autolinking is not yet available on macOS. See the Manual linking steps for macOS below.

Manually link the library on macOS
Open your project .xcodeproj on xcode.

Right click on the Libraries folder and select Add files to "yourProjectName".

Add RNCNetInfo.xcodeproj (located at node_modules/@react-native-community/react-native-netinfo/macos) to your project Libraries.

Go to Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries and add: libRNCNetInfo-macOS.a.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/netinfo#manual-linking-macos